# Xaxis should get aligned at (0,0) in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, negative-number, x-axis

I want to align xaxis line and axis labels at position (0,0) when data contains negative values.
ex. consider this fiddle example where negative values bar goes down and xaxis is set at (0,0)
http://jsfiddle.net/13d54mp8/2/

```
   var YTD = 'YTD';
   var yr1 = 'Year 1';
   var yr3 = '*3 Year';
   var yr5 = '*5 Year';
   var sinceIN = '* Since Inception (5/31/2012)';
   
   $(function() {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
     chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        events: {
          load: function() {
            var xx = (-1) * (this.yAxis[0].translate(0, false, false));
            this.xAxis[0].axisGroup.translate(0, xx);
            this.xAxis[0].labelGroup.translate(0, xx);
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Report Title',
        style: {
          fontSize: '18px',
          color: '#1D5293',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: '(As of 6/30/2012)',
        style: {
          fontSize: '18px',
          color: '#1D5293'
        },
        y: 40
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: [YTD, yr1, yr3, yr5, sinceIN],
        lineColor: '#C1BADB',
        tickWidth: 2,

      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        lineColor: '#C1BADB',
        lineWidth: 1,
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return this.value + '%';
          }
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        tickWidth: 2

      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '%';
        },
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
          name: 'XXX Company Ltd. (Net)',
          data: [3.02, -0.61, 2.03, 1.51, 5.35],
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#333',
            formatter: function() {
              return this.y + '%'
            }
          },
          color: '#1D5293'
        },
        {
          name: 'XXX Relative Return Index (Gross)**',
          data: [2.45, 0.85, 4.11, 0.73, 3.56],
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#333',
            formatter: function() {
              return this.y + '%'
            }
          },
          color: '#9E9E9E'
        }
      ],
      legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'top',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 50,
        y: 65,
        borderWidth: 0,
        margin: 30
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Now I want to make work the same use case for inverted column chart where xaxis is on top and yaxis is at right side. check fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fa2e80qu/3/

```
    var YTD = 'YTD'
var yr1 = 'Year 1'
var yr3 = '*3 Year'
var yr5 = '*5 Year'
var yr7 = '*7 Year'
var yr9 = '*9 Year'
var sinceIN = '* Since '

$(function() {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                events: {
                    load: function() {
                        var xx = (0.34)* (this.yAxis[0].translate(0, false, false));
                        this.xAxis[0].axisGroup.translate(0, xx);
                        this.xAxis[0].labelGroup.translate(0, xx);

                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Report Title',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '18px',
                    color: '#1D5293',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '(As of 6/30/2012)',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '18px',
                    color: '#1D5293'
                },
                y: 40
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [YTD, yr1, yr3, yr5, yr7,yr9, sinceIN],
                lineColor: '#C1BADB',
                tickWidth: 2,
                opposite:true
            
            },
            yAxis: {
            opposite:true,
                reversed:true,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                lineColor: '#C1BADB',
                lineWidth: 1,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value + '%';
                    }
                },
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                tickWidth: 2

            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '%';
                },
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [
                {
                name: 'XXX Company Ltd. (Net)',
                data: [3.02, -0.61, 2.03, 1.51, 5.35, -0.50,2.5],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#333',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y + '%'
                    }
                },
                color: '#1D5293'},
            {
                name: 'XXX Relative Return Index (Gross)**',
                data: [2.45, 0.85, 4.11, 0.73, 3.56,-0.5,1.6],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#333',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y + '%'
                    }
                },
                color: '#9E9E9E'}
            ],
            legend: {
                enabled:false,
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'top',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: 50,
                y: 65,
                borderWidth: 0,
                margin: 30
            },
        });
    });

});
```

Expected behavior is to have xaxis line and labels aligns properly at position (0,0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toPixels` method:

```
  chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var xx = this.yAxis[0].toPixels(0) - this.plotTop;
        this.xAxis[0].axisGroup.translate(0, xx);
        this.xAxis[0].labelGroup.translate(0, xx);

      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/07rej16z/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, When I first hit your given fiddle url then xaxis was not aligned but when I click on run button then it got aligned. Is it something due to load event?

Comment: Hi @Purva Kshatriya, Have you tested it multiple times? I have not encountered such behavior.

Comment: Okay. Will verify it again. Also, when I resize the chart, it gets misaligned and not on 0 positioned.

Comment: I found above fiddle from highcharts forum . Do you have any idea about -1 multiplier factor? why it is multiplied by -1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, because you need to use `render` instead of `load` event, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bx9w7jhm/. About the translate method - you need to investigate how it works: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/Core/Axis/Axis.ts#L4541